# React Native can not build for iOS

Tags: react-native

I have a react native app that built nicely in XCode 8.x and ran on simulator.

I have XCode 7.3 on a separate computer.  When I try to build my react-native application, I get the error message:

> Property 'badgeColor' nout found on object of type 'UITabBarItem'

Has anyone encountered this issue and how do you resolve it?  Is this an XCode version issue?

Comment: this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14423) describes few possible workarounds. And [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12080) suggests updating XCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see in those line RCTTabBarItem.m

```
       // badgeColor available "since iOS 10"
  if ([self.barItem respondsToSelector:@selector(badgeColor)]) {
    self.barItem.badgeColor = badgeColor;
  }
```

i think you should update your version xcode, & see that comments with "***badgeColor available since iOS 10"***

or you want to check version of youre xcode in terminal, type this "**xcodebuild** **-showsdks**" & will showing :

```
byewebstersmbp:react_project webster$ xcodebuild -showsdks
OS X SDKs:
    OS X 10.11                      -sdk macosx10.11

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 9.3                         -sdk iphoneos9.3

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 9.3             -sdk iphonesimulator9.3

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 9.2                        -sdk appletvos9.2

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 9.2            -sdk appletvsimulator9.2

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 2.2                     -sdk watchos2.2

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 2.2         -sdk watchsimulator2.2
```

i hope this will help you with clearly..